# Sending custom data with Media Frame Model

Tags: javascript, media

I have an option on post edit screen that can change it to full-width. Unfortunately, `$content_width` still follows the standard one with sidebar 780px (without saving the post or a whole refresh).

I have figured out the method responsible for getting this data. It's action `wp.media.model.Query.sync()` method in `js/media-models:  https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/media-models.js#L1225`

Anyone knows how to pass custom post data here (layout=full) with this AJAX request? (I will filter on that AJAX request to set `$content_width=1170`).